# Rails - Show changes after PATCH

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, mongoid, user-feedback

I would like to show the users which fields have been modified following his PUT/PATCH request

For example, I have a big "project" form, with several fields, but my user decided to only update the deadline and the project name. After he clicks the "save" button, I would like to show some message saying "You have successfully updated : name, deadline"

If it's possible, I would like some generic code that would detect the update action and infer the variable name. By generic I mean, I want to implement this in my ApplicationController, so I don't have to add code in every controller#update action

Let's look at this sample code from  *controllers/entreprise_controller.rb*

```
def update
    if @entreprise.update_attributes(entreprise_params)
      redirect_to @entreprise, notice: "Entreprise éditée"
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
end
```

Here's an idea of steps to reach my goal. Could you help me with each of these ? Or suggest a better approach ?

- Detect that we are doing a CRUD `update` action, for example from the action name in the code, that should always be `update` (how can I read, from the code, the name of the action being executed ?)
- Guess the variable name : here `@entreprise`, it can be inferred from the file for example (or maybe calling `self.class` and doing some regex ?)
- Save the list of variables that are going to be updated (maybe some tricks involving `before_action` and `after_action` and dirty_tracking ? See my edit.)
- Provide this list as a GET argument for the `redirect to @entreprise` (should be pretty straightforward)
- Show this list to the user (this part is OK for me)

**EDIT** concerning Dirty Tracking

Mongoid already implements this. However the main problem is getting the intermediate variable before it is saved. Each controller instanciates the variable like `@entreprise` during a `before_action` callback. And if I add a `before_action` in my ApplicationController, it will fire before, so no variable is available yet. And as regards a possible `after_action` in ApplicationController, the doc says "Any persistence operation clears the changes." so it's dead already. I probably cannot get away without rewriting every controller ?

Dirty Tracking & controller in a nutshell :

1. prepend_before_action
2. `before_action` of ApplicationController
3. `before_action` of EntrepriseController (which includes set_entreprise, where the variable `@entreprise` is defined so as to proceed with update)
4. If we can get a callback to HERE, it would let us inspect the object for dirty tracking information, as the object exist in memory, we can use `@entreprise.attributes=entreprise_params` and look at the dirty info (where entreprise_params is the strong parameters for @entreprise)
5. action : on success, it will store the info in the DB, and we lose dirty tracking info
6. `after_action`

Comment: You can look at [ActiveModel Dirty](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html) to track changes.

Comment: Yeah I'm well aware of that, I just don't know how I can use it without changing the code of every controller... see my edit (I can reformulate if it isn't clear).